Can multi-threading improve performance of an IO-bound process?
I am trying to understand the difference between CPU Bound vs IO Bound process. ChatGPT suggested that multi-threading/parallel processing can help a CPU bound process; However, I think that having multithreading can help with IO Bound process.
Let's say the application is talking with some API, and has to make various API calls. If we have multi-threading, we can make those API calls in parallel, and boost the performance.

Think of it this way: if you have a restaurant with one cook and multiple waiters, once the chef is maxed out, adding more waiters won't get the meals on the tables any faster.

@CharlesE.Grant so waiters are threads, and chef is network IO call like an API call in your analogy?

Yes, that's the idea. When you have a limited resource (network bandwidth for example) simply throwing more requests at it doesn't improve matters. Keep in mind that sending a data packet over the network is a physical process that takes time. You can't make it go faster than the physical constraints of the network allow.

If chatgpt claimed this then you should ask chatgpt to defend its assertion.

Async and threads aren’t magic, they always result in more work. More work generally equals more time, but when that extra work is done in an otherwise downtime, the effect is for the process to be faster even though all of the individual pieces take the same or more time.

A couple of misconceptions here: 1. Slow API calls are not in general "I/O" in the sense of "IO Bound" (compare reading/writing to disk) - the network interface is not in general saturated. 2. You can make parallel API calls without multithreading - for instance with an async API, or careful use of select() etc in a single thread, or multiple processes.

@StackExchangeSupportsIsrael Could you please explain more. What do you mean by word calculator? I have been using it a lot at work, so you comment might help me a lot there.

I/O performance has two aspects that you must distinguish: latency and throughput. One measures how long you have to wait for the first byte of a response, the other how long you have to wait additionally for the last byte.
As pjc50 said, if your network link is already saturated (no more packets can go through) it doesn't matter how smartly you organize your program - even a quantum computer couldn't help you.
But if your bottleneck is mainly lag (e.g. a web API that takes five seconds to respond at all), then sending requests in parallel will absolutely speed things up, and multi-threading is a convenient way of doing that.

As I asked elsewhere, what branch of Computer Science entails these concepts. Most of the jargons used here feel vary unfamiliar. If I want to improve my expertise in these concepts, what subject of computer science should I be focussing on?

@Eric  Technically, threads, processes, etc. are all just specific means to achieve a speedup over naive sequential execution. The most useful general term to research is probably concurrency.

@Eric: This is less Computer Science -- which mostly concerns itself with theory, so a lot of algorithm, data-structures, etc... -- and more Software Engineering -- which concerns itself with practical applications, including performance.

While it used to be the case that multithreading was the most convenient way to make multiple I/O requests concurrently, most modern languages and frameworks make it so easy to make concurrent I/O requests asynchronously (in a single thread) that this is by far the best option nowdays. It is better because there is no overhead of extra threads, there's no danger of hard-to-debug faults due to data sharing between threads, and the code is simpler. See JimmyJames answer, which really ought to be the accepted one IMO.

@IanGoldby: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't asynchronously running tasks just threads under the hood? Just with threads whose main task is to check "Did I get the thing? No? Then I'll wait a bit and check again.", as opposed to a series of threads that do additional stuff while that one thread is still trying to do something.

@AlexanderThe1st Not really. With a typical async I/O API, a thread tells the kernel, "I want data on either socket A or socket B. Wake me up whenever you get some data for me to read." Then the thread goes to sleep. When the kernel gets data on either socket, it wakes up the thread, and tells it, "I got some data on socket A and/or B. You can read it from the socket right away." And then the thread processes the data according to which socket it is. There's no busy-looping or multithreading (apart from the kernel waking up the sleeping thread), just an event loop.

My understanding is that asynchrononous code is to threading as break and continue statements are to goto: fundamentally the same, but limited in what is exposed to the programmer.

Unless it's truly a FULL network (Very rarely the  actual problem), having multiple requests going on at once can make a huge difference since you are mostly waitting for traffic to make a round-trip and the processing on the remote machine.  The problem is that if you go from 1 connection at a time to 1000, you are putting 1000x the load on the network and 1000x the load on the target machine.  If you don't own the target machine it's quite rude.  Also the target will quickly become the new bottleneck.  I've done this and always run tests at different thread--too many will make things worse.

@AlexanderThe1st Stephen Cleary put it very well in his article There is no thread. Over 10 years old but still a good read.

(In this context, I think lag is more usually called latency.)

@IanGoldby: That read did make me think it was worth still reading it as threads, since at some point, the asynchronous method does have to "borrow" a thread from an interrupt the way they phrased it. That said, I do think that LegionMammal978's explanation clears it up - while there is a thread, it simply does not loop - it's just telling another part of code to start it up when it has something it can work with. From the perspective of the developer then, it's just a dormant thread, like an egg that's waiting to hatch, when using async?

@AlexanderThe1st: More generall,y especially if one is dealing with microcontrollers rather than Windows or Unix systems, asynchronous I/O is generally handled with interrupts.  When an I/O device is ready for more data, the CPU will force the current thread to perform an asynchronous subroutine call to an I/O handler routine.  When that routine returns, control will return to whatever code had been running before.  The difference between that and multi-threading is that the I/O routine must run to completion before the main thread can do anything else (the routine may ask the hardware...

...to interrupt it again in future, but any future interrupt would be executed from the beginning, and run to completion, before the main code could do anything else.

If you are truly I/O bound, such as your network link being saturated, then no matter how many processes you run you will not be able to transmit requests and receive responses any faster.
If you are I/O bound, adding processes does not give you more I/O capability.

making API calls with multiple threads should boost performance? Single thread 100 API calls, 10 parallel threads, 10 calls each. What am I misunderstanding?

@Eric it would only help, if your communication channel is not busy. If your network allows for 1Gb troughput, there is no way you can get 2Gb out of it with threading. If your network is not completely busy, you are not IO bound.

So, in your opinion, what factors can boost IO-Bound process performance? ChatGPT mentioned improved network speed as one.

What area of Computer Science entails these topics? If I want to improve my understanding of such topics (IO-Bound, CPU-Bound), what area should I be focussing on?

@Basilev, if you have 1 Gbit throughput and a single core 1 Gigabit is the limit. But you might have two further cores that can compress 2Gbit  to 1 Gbit in a second, transfer the compressed data, and decompress at the full speed on the receiver. So there is latency, but you can move effectively 2Gbit per second.

@Eric this is typically covered in course in operating systems or a "computer systems" course. I like the text Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective


Let's say the application is talking with some API, and has to make various API calls. If we have multi-threading, we can make those API calls in parallel, and boost the performance.

This is correct. ChatGPT's answer is the way it is because there are ways to achieve this goal that better make use of the system resources. It doesn't understand anything which results in this superficial answer.
Assume, for the sake of argument, that you have an application which is non-threaded and makes heavyweight IO calls such as retrieving data from a webservice.  In this situation, your application is paused or 'blocked' while that IO is happening. A common solution to this in years past was to add multithreading. That allows the blocked thread to wait on IO (it wasn't doing anything anyway) while other threads continue to execute. This works even on a system where there's only one CPU because the OS can switch thread contexts without any direct interaction from the application.
This is great but we can do better. Threads aren't free. They take up system resources and switching thread contexts also has a real, measurable, cost. There are limits to the number of threads a given system can run without becoming so bogged down in thread management that it can't do much else.
This brings us to 'non-blocking IO'. In this approach, the thread no longer stops executing while waiting for IO. Instead, it 'drops off a message at the IO mailbox' does some other things and comes back later to get the response. This allows the application to avoid IO waits without additional threads and the overhead associated with them. You can do everything on one thread. It's hard to understate the value of this. The addition of async/await to Python and made it a much more appealing language for IO-heavy solutions.
However, non-blocking IO only helps because when you are waiting on IO, there's nothing to do on the CPU.  If you want to execute computations at the same time within in a single application, non-blocking IO doesn't help. And really, running multiple threads on a single CPU will not help either: the CPU only works on one thread at a time. To truly have parallel/concurrent processing within a single process, you need multiple threads running on more than one CPU.
This brings us back to the original claim: multithreading can help with CPU-bound processes. That might be true, depending on what kind of processing it is. Multithreading can also help with IO-bound processes but it's not really the preferred approach. You are not wrong, but an even deeper understanding can allow you to build more optimal solutions.

From the CPU point of view, I/O is most of the time waiting for something to happen elsewhere (read also "Must-know numbers for every software engineer"):

The CPU could gain time by doing something else while waiting. This does not require multithreading, just hardware interrupts and a clever software design. But the latter part is very difficult to design and even more to implement.
This is where multithreading comes in. Multithreading facilitates the design of such clever software, leaving different threads for different I/O task waiting on ice while the CPU is running other active threads. This was already true 40 years ago without hardware thread support (although multithreading at that time decreased overall system performance except for I/O):

Nowadays, multi-threaded-multi-core CPUs bring it to the next level. If you benchmark non-I/O threads on modern CPUs you will find out that within the hardware boundaries: the more threads, the (slightly) slower each separate thread will run, but cumulated performance of all the threads will be far superior than running the same computations on a single thread. So, multithreading boosts the overall system throughput by taking advantage of the hardware throughput improvements and adding the I/O waiting time optimization.

Nice article. I'd like to see the numbers given in consistent units, though. I'm not sure it's completely obvious that an IO trip from the USA to India and back is more than billion times slower than an L1 cache reference.

"But the latter part is very difficult to design and even more to implement." - that used to be the case but modern languages and frameworks provide asynchronous operations, making it now arguably simpler than threads (and more performant).

@IanGoldby Indeed. No longer need to write assembler routines,  making sure that the code is reentrant, in case of multiple interrupts interrupting each other. The first native language support in this regard was ADA83 if I remember well, followed closely by Modula-2 before all mainstream languages followed.

@JimmyJames Distance-induced latency is just one example. Your I/O request could be to a machine in the next room, but that request may involve a lengthy database query which doesn't in and of itself prevent your machine from doing something else while it runs.

@chepner That's true, it was just one example exactly as I intended as that's what is appropriate for a comment.

In general, multi-threading access to a single resource (CPU, network, disk, etc.) will not improve performance.  Multi-threading will improve performance when the theads access different resources.
Multiple cores improve performance by increasing the capability of the CPU resource.

Whether I/O or CPU bound, multi-threading may help performance, under two conditions:

The task can be broken up into elements which can be run in parallel, instead of running all steps sequentially.
The thing doing the processing is capable of doing those elements in parallel without becoming overloaded.

In your question, the latter is the network (or whatever is on the other end of the I/O). If it has the capacity to accept and process many requests at once, multi-threading may help performance. If it's saturated by a single request, then issuing many requests won't help.
This is why performance work is often about experimenting and tuning... doing 2 things at once might be faster than doing 1 thing at a time, but doing 20 things at the same time might be slower.

Multithreading is the alternative to single threading. If you’ve ever  saved and watched your mouse pointer turn into a spinning thingy you’ve enjoyed the benefits of multithreading. Because while one thread is waiting for the write to complete the other is keeping you entertained.
Now sure, unless you’re doing some on the fly compression that’s not making your file write go faster but that reassuring spiny thingy sure makes it feel faster.
This assumes what’s being saved needs no extra work done to save. Which is typical.
Back in the day saving used to mean the computer fully stopped responding. Now you can watch cat videos while saving your massive spreadsheet. It’s not really faster. Just feels that way.

I feel like a better multithreading implementation would avoid the spinning wheel entirely, and rather allow the user to continue to his work unimpeded while the save-file routine executed completely asynchronously in the background.

@JeremyFriesner they have that. Instead of replacing the pointer with the spiny thingy they put the spiny thingy next to it. Indicates you’re still allowed to click on the gui but certain things are tied up waiting for the save to finish.


Is there anything wrong with my understanding?

As long as the API is non-blocking, a single threaded system can also make those API calls in parallel. By the assumption, we are IO bound, so there is plenty of CPU time to send each request and service each response, as they arrive.

But aren't the typical API calls always blocking. For e.g. requests module in python, you make the API call, and wait for the response.

@Eric no, typical systems have non-blocking APIs. There may be blocking wrappers around those, but non-blocking is the norm.

Blocking APIs in a thread block that thread, but other threads can keep running. If you have four cores and 20 threads, 16 threads can be blocked and the other four still run at full speed.

@Eric I've just looked at the timeline, and the requests module comes from a point in Python's history where a blocking api was much simpler to use than a non-blocking api, it predates async / await. A number of libraries came later, and were able to chose to be non-blocking whilst still being simple to use. The underlying system calls these libraries use to do networking are all non-blocking.

Yes, multithreading can absolutely help with I/O-bound process performance (as well as with CPU-bound performance of course).
Here is an example for I/O-bound speedup of 100%. Imagine you implement an algorithm to copy a file in a file system (plain old hard drive or SSD, mounted locally). The core loop will be something like this:

Initialize a buffer of 1 MB
Read up to 1 MB of data from the source file to the buffer
Write the buffer to the target file
Repeat until end-of-file

Assume that the source and destination files are on different physical drives, and that all other components in the computer (CPU, RAM, Caches, etc.) are much faster than the physical storage so can be neglected here.
Written without multithreading, this will take as long as it takes to read all bytes from the source file, plus the time it takes to write them to the destination file.
A multithreaded variant using a ring buffer would be:

Tread 0:

Initialize a ring buffer of 10 MB
Initialize global multithreading-safe variables HEAD := 0, TAIL := 0, FINISHED := 0
Start Thread 1
Start Thread 2
Wait until both are finished
Exit the process


Thread 1:

Start loop

Read up to 1 MB from the source file and place them at location HEAD * 1 MB in the ring buffer.
If (HEAD + 1) MOD 10 == TAIL, wait until they are not.
Update HEAD := (HEAD + 1) MOD 10


Repeat until end-of-file.
Set global variable FINISHED := TRUE.
End thread.


Thread 2:

Start loop

Wait while HEAD == TAIL AND NOT FINISHED.
End thread if HEAD == TAIL.
Write the 1-MB block starting at TAIL * 1 MB to the destination file.
Update TAIL := (TAIL + 1) MOD 10


Repeat



The overall time for this will be variable, but roughly on the order of the maximum of the individual times for reading the whole file and writing the whole file (so half of the time used in the single-threaded algorithm, assuming those operations take roughly the same time), plus the time for writing a random small number of blocks (since thread 2 must by definition trail a bit after thread 1).
In other words, for huge files, the multithreaded approach will be roughly twice as fast (assuming reading and writing take the same time, and assuming it's separate physical devices for the two files).
The same principle works for all kinds of I/O, not only file system but also network or direct access to chipset I/O pins or or keyboard input or whatever you have.
Also note that there are very different ways to implement parallelism for I/O, not only multi-threading; for example there is the concept of multi-processing which feels somewhat similar to multi-threading but "looks" quite different. There is event-driven I/O (or multiplexing) which is implemented totally differently from the application point of view (and does not even require or use multi-threading), but will lead to similar results if the CPU required for the I/O operations is negligible.
In fact, when looking at low(ish) level Unix-style I/O sockets, it is totally normal to use these kinds of operations (i.e. the select multiplexing scheme); blocking on I/O by default is kind of a convenience programmers use when very little parallelism or scaling is required.

It is worth noting that the same result could be achieved in a single thread, using non-blocking calls. Depending on the technology chosen, either approach may be easier.

Yup, that is what the last two paragraphs are about (event-driven/multiplexed I/O) - at the end of the day, from the point of view of the I/O system(s), it does not matter what technology was used in the CPU to achieve the same results. @JørgenFogh

To the downvoters: OP asked "can multithreading..." and I am showing a very concrete and intentionally basic example how multithreading indeed can do that. If you have a problem with the answer, I would be interested in a comment so I can improve it.

Non-blocking calls run on their own threads.

Not always, @gnasher729 - non-blocking I/O calls (at least on Linux/Unix like systems; and speaking of the kind I mean in the answer when contrasting to user-level multithreading approaches) are handled by the kernel, separate from threads. You can implement them using multithreading as well, of course.

A trivial case is a computer with two hard drives. You can have one thread reading from the first hard drive, and another writing to the second hard drive. The most extreme example I have seen was a home-made floppy disk duplication machine which wrote to eight floppy disk drives in parallel.
Often you can change an algorithm to reduce I/O. If you have a newer Mac, any data written to a swap file (I/O bound) will be compressed before writing and decompressed after reading. This reduces the size of I/O wear and tear on the disk drive, and the compression is so fast that the operation is overall faster. More because compression makes more RAM available so swapping is not even needed and the I/O completely gone.
